# Como hacer que un programa hecho en java se ejecute al iniciar el Windows?

Tags: java, windows

tengo la siguiente duda, cree un programa en java usando el IDE netbeans, y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacer que este programa se inicie al encender el pc, osea que el mismo programa tenga el poder de agregarse al inicio de windows y no tener que agregarlo manualmente.

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: ¿Quieres que el programa se abra cuando inicia windows? o ¿Quieres agregar el programa en el menú inicio de windows? o ¿Ambos?

Comment: Quiero se abra cuando se inicia windows

Comment: Podrías escribir una key en el registro de Windows. [Echa un ojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953525/run-java-application-at-windows-startup).

Comment: Pero la pregunta es como hacer que el programa se inicie con windows sin necesidad que yo tenga que añadirlo al registro, puedo hacer que el programa cree una key en el registro de windows?

Comment: Aquí se explica como hacerlo desde el propio código: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838671/starting-a-java-application-at-startup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows, desde Windows 95 hasta Windows 10, permite añadir cualquier programa a la lista de aplicaciones que se ejecutan al inicio simplemente añadiendo un acceso directo en la carpeta *Inicio*, que suele estar en

```
C:\Users\<usuario>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Pero por si acaso se ha configurado en otra unidad o no quieres/puedes averiguar el usuario actual , puedes acceder mediante variables de entorno:

```
%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Esto es válido desde Windows Vista en adelante, en versiones anteriores la carpeta se encontraba en otras rutas.

Comment: Ojo, al ser un programa java probablemente sea un jar y lo que tenga que añadir sea un acceso directo a un bat que tenga la llamada al java.

Comment: Si eso lo se, pero mi pregunta era dirigida a si el en mi programa podria hacer que se agregara al inicio de windows (con algun tipo de codigo) sin que el usuario debe agregarlo manualmente

Comment: Puedes hacer que tu programa haga eso: crear un acceso directo se puede automatizar, por eso te puse lo de la variable de entorno

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría lo siguiente:

1. Generar tu el fichero JAR de tu programa y ponerlo en un directorio 
   fijo que conozas. Por ejemplo `c:/miprograma/miprograma.jar`
2. Crear un fichero .bat con la siguiente línea: `java -jar    "C:\miprograma\miprograma.jar"` y lo pones en el mismo directorio que
   .jar con el nombre que quieras. Quedaría así:
   c:/miprograma/miprograma.bat
3. Creas un acceso directo a `"c:/miprograma/miprograma.bat"` y lo pones    en la ruta

   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
       Menu\Programs\Startup

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo yo pienso que la forma mas rápida y sencilla de hacerlo seria....

1.Creas un acceso directo del programa en cuestión.

2.Pulsas la tecla de windows + R (esto abre la ventana de ejecuciones de windows).

3.Escribes shell:startup (esto abre el directorio donde se ejecutan los programas de inicio).

4.Pon tu acceso directo ahí.

Ya esta!!!

Comment: Si eso lo se, pero mi pregunta era dirigida a si el en mi programa podria hacer que se agregara al inicio de windows sin que el usuario debe agregarlo manualmente, ya que el programa se va a usar en varios computadores

Comment: Ya he visto que has editado o refotmulado la pregunta...  voy a buscar la solución ya que a mi también me intriga saber hqcer eso 

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo yo pienso que la forma mas rápida y sencilla de hacerlo seria....

1.Creas un acceso directo del programa en cuestión.

2.Pulsas la tecla de windows + R (esto abre la ventana de ejecuciones de windows).

3.Escribes shell:startup (esto abre el directorio donde se ejecutan los programas de inicio).

4.Pon tu acceso directo ahí.

Ya esta!!!

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Esta es otra forma un poco mas hacer lo mismo pero de forma automática.

Para ello he tenido que recurrir a C# y no me he complicado la vida...
Lo que vamos hacer es crear un pequeño programa en C# que cree el acceso directo de nuestro programa exe.

```js
using System;
using System.IO;


namespace AccesoDirecto
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new CrearAccesoDirecto();
        }
    }
}

class CrearAccesoDirecto
{
    public CrearAccesoDirecto()
    {
        //Primer argumento nombre de tu acceso directo, segundo la ruta donde se contempla el archivo exe a ejecutar.
        urlShortcutToDesktop("AcesoDirecto", "C:/Programas/LectorArchive.exe");
    }

    private void urlShortcutToDesktop(string linkName, string linkUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            //Entre los dos simbolos va el nombre de tu equipo <........>
            string deskDir = "C:/Users/<.........>/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
                writer.WriteLine("URL=" + linkUrl);
                
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }catch(UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No se puede acceder a este directorio \n" + e);
        }
        catch(DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error en la ruta no encontrada \n" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Una vez tenga el archivo exe de este programa encargado de crear el acceso directo, lo dejas al lado de tu programa mismo en la carpeta que sea.

En tu código java añades este fragmento de código....

```js
package programa;

import java.io.IOException;


/**
 * Aprende Java con Yacoobs
 * @author Yacoobs C. M. 
 * https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChFlaF3Ji9vWhizWyhBQdBg?view_as=subscriber
 * Para contactar conmigo: reyrelampago2005@gamil.com
 * Dia Creación 05-mar-2019
 * Tiempo Creación 00:00:00
 * 
 */

public class Programa 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
        { 
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getProperty("user.home")+ "/desktop/CrearAcceso.exe");
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

Hay que tener en muy en cuenta las direcciones donde se encuentra tu carpeta de directorio de programa ya que hay que modificar las direcciones dependiendo de tu código a mi ejemplo (ten esto muy en cuenta). Lo mismo pasa con la ruta donde se aloja el programa que se encarga de crear los accesos directos..
El problema que sufre esto es que si modificas la ruta de tu programa al hacer la instalación todo esto deja de tener sentido y no funciona. para ello habría que crear un programa mucho mas complejo... SALUDOS